# Can you polymorph an unconscious creature that is at 0 HP to wake it up?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, hit-points, unconscious

The *polymorph* spell mentions that the creature assumes the new form's hp. As long as that hp doesn't hit 0 hp, the creature doesn't revert. But it doesn't state that you can't *polymorph* a creature at 0 hp.

As such, could you technically *polymorph* an unconscious creature to prematurely wake it up?

Answer (score 52):

## No.

From the *Polymorph* spell description:

> This spell can't affect a target that has 0 hit points.

Of note: this caveat was added in the [Player's Handbook Errata](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PH-Errata-V1.pdf), as pointed out by Thyzer, after the original printing. Some PHBs may not contain this text, but it nonetheless is the intended rules.

---

Other spells with polymorphing effects don't work either:

*True Polymorph* says

> Choose one creature with at least 1 hit point

and *Mass Polymorph* adds temporary hit points for the new form, but since your base hit points are still at 0, you'll remain unconscious.

Comment: Is this also true of *True Polymorph* and *Mass Polymorph*? What about the *Polymorph Blade*?

Comment: @goodguy5 I don't have a copy of any source material with the *Polymorph Blade*, so I'm not going to include this in my answer, but from what I can gather from various forum posts and other accessible content, it seems the *Blade* applies the effects of the *Polymorph* spell, which have already been shown to not work on 0hp creatures.

Comment: @inthemanual the key text for the polymorph blade is "On a failed save the creature also suffers the effects of a polymorph spell"